# how to open automatically MYSQL on start up of computer? or is there a downloadable software for it?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm using xampp to start my mysql server but i want to start it automatically on start up of
my computer. Is there anyway i could make my Xampp (MYSQL) opens automatically on start up?

Comment: Windows? Add MySQL services to startup. Type this command on (Win + R): `services.msc` and you will get an interface for that

Comment: Yes I'm using windows ill try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `MySQL` as one of your computer's services so it would run automatically on start-up. If you are using Windows OS, then probably, your XAMPP is installed on `C:\XAMPP\`. Now, go to your XAMPP directory and right click `xampp-control.exe` run it as administrator and the XAMPP control panel will pop-up. Check the box beside MySQL, that is the box under Service column and is beside the MySQL Module. Mostly, a UAC or user account control will pop-up asking you some stuff, just accept it and install the MySQL service to your PC. If everything is done correctly, your MySQL service should automatically start when your computer boot up.

Comment: Thank you it worked! also i did what Hanky Panky commented, I opened services.msc and make it automatic on start up

Answer (score 0):

you need to your xamp application to you startup item of windows/linux check the following link for windows

http://www.wikihow.com/Alter-Startup-Programs-in-Windows-XP

Answer (score 0):

If you  are using `windows` Operating system, then put xampp in your `startup`.

`Startup` will be available in your `start menu -> all programs`

Answer (score 0):

1.Open your xampp-control panel in this folder path xampp\xampp-control.exe.
2. Just make a tick mark on service!

[to see the image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmMKi.jpg)
OR

For Window: see the Links below

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html